# Indenting lines of multiple line object in loop

Tags: python, loops, format

I'm attempting to indent the following output

```
Thresh
Communication is key when making use of Thresh's lantern.
Let your teammates know how you like to use it.
Death Sentence and Flay can be combined in either cast order for powerful 
combinations.
Thresh can collect souls without needing to kill units himself.
Planning your map position to be near the most deaths will help to maximize 
soul collection.
```

And I want it to be indented to look like the following:

```
 Thresh
  Communication is key when making use of Thresh's lantern.
  Let your teammates know how you like to use it.
  Death Sentence and Flay can be combined in either cast order for powerful 
  combinations.
  Thresh can collect souls without needing to kill units himself.
  Planning your map position to be near the most deaths will help to 
  maximize soul collection.
```

I'm using this as my code I could assign values to each instance of sting occurring but that would often be changing and it would be difficult and impractical to do if and try statements for each scenario such as having 3 tips 2 tips then 3 tips and 3 enemy tips

````
        try:
            for i in range(0,len(self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips'])):
                self.allyTips0 += self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips'][i].replace('.', '.\n').replace('!', '!\n').replace("\n ", "\n")
            self.allyTips0 = self.allyTips0
            self.allyTips0 = '```\n{0}\n{1}```'.format(champEntry, self.allyTips0)

        except Exception as e:
            raise e
````

Answer (score 2):

The textwrap library is designed to help with this scenario. This is a sample that should produce the result shown above as your sample output...

```
import textwrap

a = '''Thresh
Communication is key when making use of Thresh's lantern.
Let your teammates know how you like to use it.
Death Sentence and Flay can be combined in either cast order for powerful
combinations.
Thresh can collect souls without needing to kill units himself.
Planning your map position to be near the most deaths will help to maximize
soul collection.'''

wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(initial_indent=" ", subsequent_indent="    ")

for line in wrapper.wrap(a):
    print(line)
```

For more details, see the documentation for the [textwrap library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/textwrap.html):

Comment: It's close to exactly  what i want thank you, but the format gets altered at the first line https://pastebin.com/JL1GtEZQ pastebin to fix formatting.. Thresh should be alone in the first line sort of like a title

Comment: @oso9817 it may be more convenient to simply print the character name (i.e. Thresh) on a separate line and then print the tips on a following line, as opposed to trying to combine both features, as `textwrap`, while very powerful, may not be able to solve all problems.

Comment: OK, I tried taking out 'Thresh' just to sort the formatting first and the first line isn't tabbed even after I tried adding '\t', also when I try to assign it to a variable and print what should be 'line' outside the loop the formatting got disrupted. https://pastebin.com/ixrqf5nY

Comment: @oso9817 TextWrapper has arguments that allow you to tune some of the settings: `initial_indent` sets the indentation of the first line. In the above code, I set it to be one space `" "`. The `subsequent_indent` provides indentation for all the lines after the first line. The documentation for the textwrap library (URL above) should provide some insight into how to use this library. NOTE: It may not be the solution to all problems.